# There is no function in $L^1$ whose Fourier transform is 1/log(x)

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I need to prove that there is no odd function on $L^1$ whose Fourier transform is a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(\xi)=1/\log(\xi)$ for $\xi\geq 2$.

I am suggested to show that for every $0<\epsilon < t$ we have
$$
\left| \int_\epsilon^t \frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi} \; d\xi \right| \leq 4.
$$

Having this, I had succesfully prove that  such $g$ is not the Fourier transform of a $L^1$ function. I only need to prove the above inequality.

I proved that
$$
\int_\epsilon^t \frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi} \; d\xi = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\epsilon y}(y\sin(\epsilon)+\cos(\epsilon))-e^{-ty}(y\sin(t)+\cos(t))}{1+y^2}\; dy
$$
and I believe I can bound the latter integral, but I don't know how to proceed. Maybe I'm wrong and I chose the wrong way. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0 \le \sin x \le x, 0 \le x \le 1, \left| \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi} \; d\xi \right| \leq 1$ hence $\left| \int_\epsilon^\delta \frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi} \; d\xi \right| \leq 1, 0 \le \epsilon \le \delta \le 1$.

Applying the second mean value theorem for $1 \le \epsilon \le t, \left| \int_\epsilon^t \frac{\sin(\xi)}{\xi} \; d\xi \right|=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\left| \int_\epsilon^\delta \sin(\xi) \; d\xi \right| \le 2, 1\le \epsilon \le \delta \le t$

Putting things together, if $0< \epsilon < t \le 1$, the integral is at most $1$, if $1 \le \epsilon < t$, the integral is at most $2$ and if $0 \le \epsilon \le 1 < t$, splitting at $1$ we get that the integral is at most $3$